# Serve Webp instead of jpeg and png in Nginx and resize

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have converted all my images to webp, same filename just different extention, and would like to start serving them with Nginx. The tricky part is that i also need to resize the images base on an argument in the URL using the image filter module. Anybody has a suggestion how can i do a rewrite and get image filter to work with the webp instead of the original URI (jpeg/png)?